# Youtube fetcherWithRequest:fetcherClass not found

Tags: ios6, ios4, youtube-api, instance

I keep getting this warning:

Instance Method'-fetcherWithRequest:fetcherClass:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Here is the code that gives me the warning:

```
+ (GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *)uploadFetcherWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                    fetcherService:(GTMHTTPFetcherService *)fetcherService {
    // Internal utility method for instantiating fetchers
    GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *fetcher;
    if (fetcherService) {
        fetcher = [fetcherService fetcherWithRequest:request
                                        fetcherClass:self];
    } else {
        fetcher = (GTMHTTPUploadFetcher *) [self fetcherWithRequest:request];
    }
    return fetcher;
}
```

this is in the GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.m file copyright 2010 version 2.0 mac toolbox

I have looked in the GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.h file for the fetcherClass but didn't find anything.

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you solve it?

Everything works ok and I can upload videos to Youtube I would just like to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the correct method in another .h file found on line.  Now everything works fine and I don't get a warning.